# MATLAB:Undefined function 'detectHarrisFeatures' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab

I have installed MATLAB2015a in my linux system .
I have installed almost all packages in my system while installation of MATLAB . 
While running the below code I am getting a straneg error .Can any one help me into this :
I have required tool box :

**>> ver**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB Version: 8.5.0.197613 (R2015a)
MATLAB License Number: 88888
Operating System: Linux 3.13.0-53-generic #89~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 20 17:42:16 UTC 2015 x86_64
Java Version: Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB                                                Version 8.5        (R2015a)
Computer Vision System Toolbox                        Version 6.2        (R2015a)
Image Acquisition Toolbox                             Version 4.9        (R2015a)
Image Processing Toolbox                              Version 9.2        (R2015a)
>>
```

**`Commands:`**

```
I = checkerboard;
corners = detectHarrisFeatures(I);
imshow(I); hold on;
plot(corners.selectStrongest(50));
```

**Error:**
Undefined function 'detectHarrisFeatures' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: Do you have the computer vision toolbox installed and activated? Are the toolboxes in your [MATLAB path](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html)?

Comment: Installing "almost all packages" you probably missed the toolbox you need.

Comment: I have updated my question with the information of packages installed

Comment: What happens when you type in `help detectHarrisFeatures` or `help imshow`?

Comment: help detectHarrisFeatures
  detectHarrisFeatures Find corners using the Harris-Stephens algorithm
    points = detectHarrisFeatures(I) returns a cornerPoints object,
    points, containing information about the feature points detected in a
    2-D grayscale image I. detectHarrisFeatures uses the Harris-Stephens
    algorithm to find feature points.

Comment: I am not sure but I am having some issue in MATLAB Computer Vision System Toolbox license .

Comment: What does `license('inuse')` show you after you try to run your above code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a grayscale to use the detectHarrisFeatures function. So the correct code would be:

```
I = checkerboard;
I_grayscale = rgb2gray(I);
corners = detectHarrisFeatures(I_grayscale);
imshow(I); hold on;
plot(corners.selectStrongest(50));
```